How to add multiple images in HTML?
I just started HTML and I have a problem. When we want to add multiple images does every image require a specific tag or is there any way to add multiple images with just one or two tags?
I want to say that in Java we are able to store multiple integer values with the help of one datatype.
Does HTML have this type of feature? I want to add 10 images. Does every image require a specific tag or is there any way to add multiple values easily?
I need suggestion for easily adding multiple images.

Can you share what you have tried? Have you tried stuff in online-editors, like w3schools? Share the Html-code you have tried and show you've researched the topic, please.

HEY THANK YOU FOR SUPPORTING ME , I TRIED HARD TO INSERT MULTIPLE IMAGES IN ONE TIME BUT I CAN NOT FIND THE SOLUTION  AND NOW I HAVE NO PREVIOUS CODES RELATED INSERT MULTIPLE IMAGES    THANK YOU :)

P.S.: the etiquette is not to use all caps in comments or anywhere else for that matter. Unless you want to express anger. All caps is the digital equivalent of jelling at some one, and considered rather rude. (And I assume you do not want to be seen as yelling at us.)

As far as I know there is no way to put several src's of images inside one tag.
The way to do this is by using the <img> tag for each image.
What's more, you can create through a javascript loop and create an image every time when its routing is in the array:
html:
<body id="body">
</body>

javascript:
let body=document.getElementById("body");
const images=["img1.jpg","img2.jpg"/*and so on... */];
let img;
for(i=0;i<images.length;i++)
    {
        img=document.createElement("img");
        img.src=images[i];
        body.appendChild(img);
    }

If anyone really knows of a possibility to put several src's of images in one tag, I would appreciate it if they shared... Thanks!

I basically used the code of Agota Kristof and put it into one .html file, of which I stole the code from w3schools.com.
It's too long to be put into a comment.
Make a txt-file.
Paste the code into that .txt-file.
Change the extension from .txt to .html.
Run in browser.
Push the button.
If the answer helps you: accept Agota Kristof's answer as correct, and give me an upvote.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Demo JavaScript in Body</h2>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<div id="pictureZone">

</div>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
let body=document.getElementById("pictureZone");
const images=["https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg","https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"/*and so on... */];

for(i=0;i<images.length;i++)
    {
        let img=document.createElement("img");
        img.src=images[i];
        body.appendChild(img);
    }}
</script>

</body>
</html> 

